# Command to clear line

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm using jquery to draw lines on canvas. I have different 3 different buttons on my screen. When the user click on a specific button it draws a line. I need to clear the line when the user click on any of the other buttons. I guess my questions is what command do you use to  make sure that when the user click on any of the other button the line are not overlapping and that the previous choice is cleared. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, both your "other" buttons should handle the click event and clear the `Canvas`, I'm not sure I understand the overlapping part?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas doesn't work like 'clearing objects' because there are none. You first need to clear the canvas or a part. That happens with the following command:

```
context.clearRect ( x , y , w , h );
```

Then you can draw the new line or whatever you like.

If you need the functionality of selectable paths there's the option of using an SVG instead of Canvas.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of way to do this, for example you can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector

```
$("button.but").not("clicked").click(function() {
    $(".clicked").removeClass("clicked");
});

$("button.but").click(function() {
   $(this).addClass("clicked");
});​
```

[Here is a jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t6WmB/)

Comment: I tried this but it not working.
("#Sadline").not("#Happyline").click(function() {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(303, 362);
            context.bezierCurveTo(303, 362, 370, 280, 407, 360);  
            context.lineWidth = 10;
            // line color
            context.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
            context.stroke();
 });